# Resolve TypeScript path in jest.mock

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm adding unit tests to a TypeScript project which is using `compilerOptions.paths`, and I need to mock an import.

I'm running into an issue where jest can't resolve the module to mock

```sh
 FAIL  logic/index.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@lib/foo' from 'logic/index.test.ts'
```

I'm using `ts-jest` which adds support for paths in imports but looks like I need to do an extra step for the mocks

What is the correct way to resolve the path here?

---

SIMPLIFIED CASE

```json
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Filesystem

```
* lib
  * __mocks__
    * foo.ts
  * foo.ts
* logic
  * index.ts
  * index.test.ts
* tsconfig.json
* jest.config.js
```

```
// index.ts
import foo from '@lib/foo';

const logic = () => foo();

export default logic;
```

```
// index.test.ts
import 'jest';

import logic from '.';

jest.mock('@lib/foo');
```

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Comment: How is your project set up? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping)? https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1165 suggests this problem is in how Jest handles the mocking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, may have missed `moduleNameMapper` in jest config, trying now..

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, it was missing `'^@lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/$1',` from `moduleNameMapper`; if you post as the answer I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the `ts-jest` docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/), when you're using `compilerOptions.paths` you need to update Jest's `moduleNameMapper` accordingly. The library supplies a utility to build the appropriate mapping for you:

```
// jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');

const { compilerOptions } = require('path/to/tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(
    compilerOptions.paths,
    { prefix: '<rootDir>/' },
  ),
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Alternatively you can do it manually, in your case:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: { '^@lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/$1' },
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Comment: Using `pathsToModuleNameMapper` still didn't work as it wasn't going to the `<rootDir>`, I had to specify the mapping manually, but this is what was missing

Comment: @PaulS. updated, the utility provides for that too!